# "Killed" processes and django/gunicorn memory footprint

Tags: python, django, memory, gunicorn, postgresql-9.3

I was seeing some `Killed` messages in my logs for my gunicorn processes and sometimes when I am on the django shell, it just gets `Killed`.

After doing some research, I found that this could be lead to a lack of resource, especially memory.
I am using a vagrant VM of 512MB in development with the following stack:

```
Nginx
+
Gunicorn with 3 workers
+
3 RQ workers
+
Redis as Cache
+
Redis as DataStore (is not meant to store a lot of data, mainly used to store the queues for the workers)
+ 
PostgreSQL
```

For deployment, I initially planned to use 2 machines of 1GB each to start.
The DataBase (PostgreSQL Server) would be on one machine and all the other ones on the other machine. I am wondering whether I should change this plan based on what I found out.

```
Machine 1 of 1GB: Nginx, Gunicorn, RQ Workers, Redis Cache, Redis DataStore
Machine 2 of 1GB: PostgreSQL
```

Indeed, when I looked at the memory consumption, I saw that it was more gunicorn and the RQ workers that were consumming a lot of RAM. About 45MB each process, and there are 7 processes (4 Gunicorn + 3 RQ workers).

1) Is it a normal memory footprint for a django application?

2) Could these processes grow even bigger?

3) Also, any idea of what are the `postgres: my_project my_project 10.0.0.51 idle` processes?

```
(venv)mike@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/local/sites/my_project$ ps aux --sort=-rss,-vsz | head -21
USER           PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
my_project   24650  0.2  8.7 161200 44072 ?        S    19:14   0:02 /var/local/sites/my_project/venv/bin/python /projects/my_project/webapp/manage.py rqworker high
my_project   24654  0.2  8.7 161188 44072 ?        S    19:14   0:02 /var/local/sites/my_project/venv/bin/python /projects/my_project/webapp/manage.py rqworker high default low
my_project   24651  0.2  8.7 161184 44068 ?        S    19:14   0:02 /var/local/sites/my_project/venv/bin/python /projects/my_project/webapp/manage.py rqworker high default low
my_project   26144  0.2  8.6 163612 43628 ?        S    19:14   0:01 /var/local/sites/my_project/venv/bin/python /var/local/sites/my_project/venv/bin/gunicorn my_project.wsgi:application --name my_project_app --workers 3 --user=my_project --group=my_project --log-level=info --bind=unix:/tmp/my_project.gunicorn.sock --access-logfile=/projects/my_project-logs/vm_logs/gunicorn-my_project-access.log --log-file=/projects/my_project-logs/vm_logs/gunicorn-my_project.log
my_project   26143  0.2  8.6 163596 43608 ?        S    19:14   0:01 /var/local/sites/my_project/venv/bin/python /var/local/sites/my_project/venv/bin/gunicorn my_project.wsgi:application --name my_project_app --workers 3 --user=my_project --group=my_project --log-level=info --bind=unix:/tmp/my_project.gunicorn.sock --access-logfile=/projects/my_project-logs/vm_logs/gunicorn-my_project-access.log --log-file=/projects/my_project-logs/vm_logs/gunicorn-my_project.log
my_project   26139  0.2  8.6 163592 43608 ?        S    19:14   0:01 /var/local/sites/my_project/venv/bin/python /var/local/sites/my_project/venv/bin/gunicorn my_project.wsgi:application --name my_project_app --workers 3 --user=my_project --group=my_project --log-level=info --bind=unix:/tmp/my_project.gunicorn.sock --access-logfile=/projects/my_project-logs/vm_logs/gunicorn-my_project-access.log --log-file=/projects/my_project-logs/vm_logs/gunicorn-my_project.log
postgres     25660  0.0  3.2 246436 16212 ?        S    19:14   0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf
my_project   26102  0.0  2.4  56704 12332 ?        S    19:14   0:00 /var/local/sites/my_project/venv/bin/python /var/local/sites/my_project/venv/bin/gunicorn my_project.wsgi:application --name my_project_app --workers 3 --user=my_project --group=my_project --log-level=info --bind=unix:/tmp/my_project.gunicorn.sock --access-logfile=/projects/my_project-logs/vm_logs/gunicorn-my_project-access.log --log-file=/projects/my_project-logs/vm_logs/gunicorn-my_project.log
root         24615  0.0  2.3  56624 11936 ?        Ss   19:14   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf --nodaemon
postgres     25679  0.0  1.2 247668  6268 ?        Ss   19:14   0:00 postgres: my_project my_project 10.0.0.51(55189) idle
postgres     25674  0.0  1.2 247668  6264 ?        Ss   19:14   0:00 postgres: my_project my_project 10.0.0.51(55187) idle
postgres     25678  0.0  1.2 247668  6264 ?        Ss   19:14   0:00 postgres: my_project my_project 10.0.0.51(55188) idle
postgres     25683  0.0  1.2 247668  6264 ?        Ss   19:14   0:00 postgres: my_project my_project 10.0.0.51(55190) idle
postgres     26547  0.0  1.2 247668  6264 ?        Ss   19:14   0:00 postgres: my_project my_project 10.0.0.51(55191) idle
postgres     26548  0.0  1.2 247668  6264 ?        Ss   19:14   0:00 postgres: my_project my_project 10.0.0.51(55192) idle
postgres     26549  0.0  1.2 247668  6264 ?        Ss   19:14   0:00 postgres: my_project my_project 10.0.0.51(55193) idle
my_project   26652  0.0  0.8  21844  4284 pts/0    Ss   19:15   0:00 -bash
root         26603  0.0  0.8 107696  4236 ?        Ss   19:15   0:00 sshd: my_project [priv]
postgres     25662  0.0  0.6 246572  3200 ?        Ss   19:14   0:00 postgres: checkpointer process
```

Comment: If you're using PostgreSQL it's a really good idea to turn the OOM killer off, disabling memory overcommit. See the manual. That'll let well written programs handle out-of-memory conditions gracefully.

Comment: @CraigRinger The redis doc says to set ```vm.overcommit_memory = 1``` which I believe does not disable the OOM Killer but change its default mode, correct? If I change it for PostgreSQL then I should make sure I only have PostegreSQL on the machine correct? It might not be the best option for some other programs.